# assimp compile error: DirectX_D3DX9_LIBRARY not found although directX is installed

Tags: makefile, cmake, directx, assimp

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

gives following error:

```
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of off64_t
Check size of off64_t - done
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - not found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - found
Looking for DirectX...
DirectX_PREFIX_PATH changed.
Found DirectX: C:/Windows/System32/d3d9.dll
DX lib dir: C:/Windows/System32
Looking for DirectX...
DirectX_PREFIX_PATH changed.
Found DirectX: C:/Windows/System32/d3d9.dll
DX lib dir: C:/Windows/System32
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
DirectX_D3DX9_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
```

I already installed DirectX but it doesnt work either. I couldnt find the solution for this. The assimp Version is 3.3.1. I already tried to compile it with Visual Studio 2017 too.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by our old model-viewer. At the moment it wants to have an installation of the old DirectX9 SDK on your machine. To fix this just look for the DX-9.0a SDK ( just google for it ) and install it at the default location.

You can also run the cmake-script with tools-support disabled. Then the DX-SDK is not required and the issue will not occurr any more:

```
assimp_root_folder>cmake CMakeLists.txt -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS=OFF
```